# how to solve this uitablview cell uitextfield focus issues

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i have created ios app. uitableview each row show on textbox. button click to move next row. default show on 10 rows. last record to scroll to another records.
here is the code

```
 if (![self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
                self.nextRow = i;
                self.nextColumn = j;               
            }
```

now scroll the table but cursor focus on last records(10). how to focus set on 11th records. here is the attachment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) class for your tableView. It will manage this by itself.

Comment: my issue of textbox redcolor show on cursor. but now previous row show on cursor. please help me how to solve this issues.

Comment: what is your button onClick action will do?